# Anatomy of a proper inheritance / subclass implementation using Google Closure Library

Tags: javascript, inheritance, google-closure, limejs

I'm getting started with Google's Closure Library (along with Lime.js), and I'm trying to create a very basic scene, with some instances of a custom-subclass of Lime.js' lime.Layer class.

As I understand (as I've read in various examples and Google's own documentation), there are 7 items that need to be in your subclass for it to inherit properly from it's intended super-class, and be available to other classes:

- goog.provide("name.of.subclass")
- goog.require("name.of.superclass")
- in comments above the constructor function @constructor
- in comments above the constructor function @extends name.of.superclass
- inside the constructor, call to name.of.superclass.call(this)
- after the constructor, goog.inherits(name.of.subclass, name.of.superclass)
- finally, export the constructor with goog.exportSymbol('name.of.subclass', name.of.subclass)

The structure of my project is simple.  "index.html" lives in the main level alongside a folder named "js", which contains all my custom JavaScript files.  I've run other simpler tests that confirm both Closure and Lime are loading and initializing correctly.  I'm just trying to take the next step into some more OO-style patterns.  My code and the errors I'm encountering are below.

---

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>LimeTest</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../closure/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/limetest.js"></script>
    </head?
    <body onload="limetest.start()"></body>
</html>
```

---

js/limetest.js

```
// Expose class
goog.provide('limetest');

// Import dependencies
goog.require('lime.Director');
goog.require('lime.Scene');
goog.require('lime.Layer');

// Import custom subclass of lime.Layer
goog.require('stupid.thing');

// Main Start function
limetest.start = function ()
{
    // setup Lime.js scene
    var director = new lime.Director(document.body, 1024, 768);
    var scene = new lime.Scene();
    var mainLayer = new lime.Layer().setPosition(512, 384);

    // instantiate subclass
    var something = new stupid.thing();

    // assemble scene
    scene.appendChild(mainLayer);
    mainLayer.appendChild(something);
    director.makeMobileWebAppCapable();
    director.replaceScene(scene);
}

// Export start method
goog.exportSymbol('limetest.start', limetest.start);
```

---

js/thing.js

```
goog.provide('stupid.thing');

goog.require('lime');
goog.require('lime.Layer');

/*
*   @constructor
*   @extends lime.Layer
 */
stupid.thing = function ()
{
    lime.Layer.call(this);
};
goog.inherits(stupid.thing, lime.Layer);

goog.export('stupid.thing', stupid.thing);
```

---

The errors I'm getting in Chrome are:

```
base.js:     634   goog.require could not find: stupid.thing
base.js:     634   goog.logToConsole_
base.js:     675   goog.require
limetest.js: 10    (anonymous function)

base.js:     677   Uncaught Error: goog.require could not find: stupid.thing
base.js:     677   goog.require
limetest.js: 10    (anonymous function)
```

---

What am I missing here?

Comment: what is all this for? i can't tell what it's supposed to do...

Comment: It's supposed to not return errors.  Obviously I have greater intents, this is just an example.  Nobody ever asks "what's the point of 'foo' and 'bar'?"

Comment: @HorsePickle: These errors don't seem to have anything to do with the inheritance implementation, do they? Please create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that produces those errors, and word your question after it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have two choices to resolving your dependencies:
1) load the dependent script manually
2) load a deps.js file, that provides the path to the dependencies

Typically, the "deps.js" is generated (does lime do this for you, I'm not familiar with it)?

As a side note, you might want to try goog.defineClass which remove some of the boilerplate from your class definitions (@constructor,@extends and goog.inherits are implied).